# Python Serializing JSON values in a Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON which I flattened using `json_normalize()`, but one of the entries had a list (as below).

The output that I am getting:

```
| org  |totalPageStatistics.clicks.mobileCustomButtonClickCounts|
|:-----|-------------------------------------------------------:|
| One  | [{'customButtonType': 'VIEW_WEBSITE', 'clicks': 0}]    |
| One  | [{'customButtonType': 'VIEW_WEBSITE', 'clicks': 3}]    |
| One  | [{'customButtonType': 'VIEW_WEBSITE', 'clicks': 4}]    |
```

How can I further flatten this JSON column?

The desired output is:

```
| org  |mobileCustomButtonClickCountsButtonType  |mobileCustomButtonClickCountsClicks|
|:-----|:---------------------------------------:|----------------------------------:|
| One  | VIEW_WEBSITE                            |0                                  |
| One  | VIEW_WEBSITE                            |3                                  |
| One  | VIEW_WEBSITE                            |4                                  |
```

Comment: Try to use `pd.json_normalize` somewhere

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

Comment: @thomask I have tried using ```json_normalize()``` but i cant seem to get it, can you please elaborate in this case specifically?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Since your code only splits the data into two columns, perhaps you can try looping over the org values and json.normalize on their values.